# exporting pybind11 modules using cmake ubuntu

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, cmake, pybind11

i've got a project structure that looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the relevant project tree]

i want to export the pyInuitiveCamera.cpp as a python module using pybind11, the code itself for the class is supposed to be fine because it worked on windows but we switched to linux (if needed ill add the source code for the actual binding). my cmake file for the binding looks something like this:

```
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_subdirectory(./cameras/pybind11/)
pybind11_add_module(pyInuitiveCamera cameras/pyInuitiveCamera.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pyInuitiveCamera VaiCore)
set_target_properties(
        pyInuitiveCamera
        PROPERTIES
        OUTPUT_NAME "pyInuitiveCamera"
        SUFFIX ".so"
)
```

this builds successfully and outputs the .so file as expected, but when trying to import it using python i get:
[image: terminal error when trying to import]

any suggestion would be welcome

Comment: try to use `c++filt` on the missing symbols then find why it is not defined (missing implementation ?).
ps: Avoid screenshot prefer snippet ```sh ... ````

Comment: ty for the ps, ill keep that i mind ;)
i ran it and it's one of the bounded functions when i use the PYBIND11_MODULE on my .cpp file